# Iterate over a dynamic table - Angular 11

Tags: angular, for-loop, dynamic

In my project I am returning a table of data from an API. I am trying to iterate over a column and make each row it's own named value, for later use. But since the data could be different every time it is called, I am not sure quite how to best do that.

```
if(this.storedData.Table2.length != null)
    {
      let sum = this.storedData.Table2[0];
      let sum1 = this.storedData.Table2[1];
      let sum2 = this.storedData.Table2[2];
      let sum3 = this.storedData.Table2[3];
      let sum4 = this.storedData.Table2[4];
      if(sum.DataId = '4')
      {
        //do logic here
      }
```

But I never know how many rows there will be, so it's almost impossible to make logic for each row. Is there a way I could do a forloop or something to dynamically add a name to each row?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use `forEach` and store each variable on an object, like so:

```
const sums = { [key: string]: <insert type of each Table2 item> }

if (this.storedData?.Table2?.length)
    {
      this.storedData.Table2.forEach((tableItem, index) => 
        sums[`sum${index || ''}`] = tableItem
      )
      
      if(sums.sum.DataId = '4')
      {
        //do logic here
      }
...
```

This will build a dynamic dictionary of objects for you, but I'm not sure what you want wanting to do with the `if` statement and the `do logic here` parts of the code. Could you elaborate your requirements a bit there please?

Comment: I couldn't get these pieces to work, can you explain more of the reasoning behind it? the if statement just assigns the values into inputs for other functions and html tags.

Comment: I've changed my answer, you'll want to use `forEach` instead of `map`. It will iterate over however many items are returned from the API and create the `sums` object, where each item is stored.